# JMeter 3.1: different results in GUI mode and non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I know load tests should be run in non-GUI mode.

**But** when I run the tests with the following command:

```
jmeter -n -t server_load_test.jmx -l log_100u_5s_01.jtl
```

**In non-GUI mode**:
I get an average response time between 3 or 4 seconds which of course is not acceptable.

**In GUI mode**:
I get an average response time of 100ms.

The test is really simple, it is just an HTTP request (GET) with 100 users in 5 seconds.

I would not have said anything if it was the other way around.

Which one should I trust?
My question is more: what is going on and how do I find the problem?

Comment: Hello, Could you provide the jmx file ? DO you ramp in 5 seconds or run your test for 5 seconds ?

Comment: I ramp in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-GUI mode consumes a way less resources that GUI mode so I would recommend looking not only into Average Response Time, but also keep in mind other important metrics, for example check delivered load in both scenarios, i.e:

- [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listeners output (both are available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project
- [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and compare the output for both scenarios
- Use 3rd-party analysis solution like [JAnalyser](http://epireum.com/page-section/janalyser/) or [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

My expectation is that in GUI mode you have much slower ramp-up hence you can run into the situation when some threads already had already finished their work while others were not yet started. In non-GUI ramp-up is faster so you have more online users so the load delivered to your application under test is much higher.

Try increasing loop count and test duration to see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those two plugins helped a lot and your explanation makes sense.